# Sitecore Read a treelist field in view rendering

Tags: tree-list

I have a template with field of type treelist which holds images, i want to read this field in my view rendering (.cshtml file) and loop over the images and display each one in an  tag. How can i do that?

Here is my code for reading from treelist:
(this code was working fine when my view was a controller rendering, however when i tried to add a view rendering it gives me error:
Inner Exception: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Sitecore.Data.Items.Item'. )

```
@model Sitecore.Data.Items.Item
@using Sitecore.Data.Fields
@using Sitecore.Data.Items
@using Sitecore.Resources.Media
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">




         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"
                class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            @{
                IEnumerable<Item> heroImages = null;
                var heroImagesField = new MultilistField(
                Model.Fields["Hero Images"]);
                if (heroImagesField != null)
                {
                    heroImages = heroImagesField.GetItems();
                }
                if (heroImages != null)
                {
                    int i = 1;
                    foreach (var image in heroImages)
                    {
                        var mediaItem = (MediaItem)image;
                        <div class="item @(i == 1 ? "active" : "") ">
                            <img src=" @MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem) "
                                 style="width:1920px;" />
                        </div>
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why move from a controller rendering to a view rendering?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel` as your model and then retrieve a Sitecore context item from it, rather then defining the `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` as a model.

So, you should change your model definition to this:

`@model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel`

P.S. Your question is covered quite well by this community forum q/a:
https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/109

Personally, I recommend looking through the community forum or Sitecore KB before submitting a question.